# What is the point of creating AMI's for EC2 instances that aren't backed by an EBS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was going to install a bunch of stuff on my EC2 instance (not EBS backed, just instance store) and then create and AMI from it.

But the documentation says:

> If you create an AMI from an instance, the data on its instance store
>   volumes isn't preserved and isn't present on the instance store
>   volumes of the instances that you launch from the AMI.

So if I install php, nginx and use composer (php dependency manager) to install more things and then create an AMI off my EC2 instance it's not going to work because the data on the instance store volumes isn't preserved? It seems like I'm misunderstanding something here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"data on its instance store volumes" - instance store volumes == volumes which are attached to the device (not including the root device)

The data on the instance's root device  will be part of the AMI, but if there's an instance store-volume (or EBS) attached to it, the data on instance store-volume/EBS volume will *not* be part of the AMI.

Though EBS volume will not be part of the AMI - it is important to note that unlike instance store-volumes, the data stored on EBS *will* be available to other instances even after the original instance (from which the AMI was created) is gone, since EBS is independent and can be detached and re-attached to different instances.

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you. Stupid of me!

Comment: @BestPractices AFAIK an EBS snapshot *will* be created but it will not be part of the AMI.

Comment: @BestPractices in case you agree with me, kindly remove the downvote. In case you still don't agree with me - please educate me!

Comment: @alfasin, you have it completely backwards.  This isn't confusing when you understand that the phrase is not *"store volumes"* -- it's *"instance store volumes"* = Ephemeral disks = **non-EBS**.  I believe the documentation uncited in the question is from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/InstanceStorage.html

Comment: ...of course, the advice in that document does not apply to the root volume of an instance store backed AMI.  That would indeed be a little pointless.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-instance-store.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for the correction. Though the answer is still valid (only the data on the root device will be saved in the AMI) it's important to make the distinction between an EBS-volume to Ephemeral disks. Answer updated to reflect it. Thanks!

Comment: You are getting warmer, but there are two issues:  first, *store volume* is not standard terminology in EC2.  Volumes come in two varieties, *instance store volumes* and *EBS volumes*.  Second, a copy of the data from snapshots of EBS volumes that you include in an AMI *is* available to machines spawned from the AMI.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot terminology corrected - thanks. As for your second comment, I never wrote that the data on the EBS will not be available - just that it will not be part of the AMI. I added a new paragraph to the answer to make sure it's clear. Please LMK if you see any inaccuracies there.

Comment: @alfasin the point is that you *can* add (non-root) EBS volumes to an AMI.  A snapshot of that volume *will* be part of the AMI, and will be used to create a new EBS volume, and the new volume will be attached to the new instance.  The documented limitation *only* applies to instance store (ephemeral) volumes, which will be attached, but blank, on the new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can customize an instance based root volume and create an AMI of that customized root volume.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-instance-store.html

> First, launch an instance from an AMI that's similar to the AMI that you'd like to create. You can **connect to your instance and customize it. When the instance is set up the way you want it, you can bundle it**. It takes several minutes for the bundling process to complete. After the process completes, you have a bundle, which consists of an image manifest (image.manifest.xml) and files (image.part.xx) that contain a template for the root volume. Next you upload the bundle to your Amazon S3 bucket and then register your AMI.